# NullReference Exception unhandled. C# Reflection

Tags: c#

```
ControlType = "System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsApplication1." + "PictureBox1";
System.Reflection.Assembly asm;
asm = typeof(Form).Assembly;
ControlObject = (System.Windows.Forms.Control)asm.CreateInstance(ControlType);
ControlObject.Name = ControlName;
```

The next code generated following exception for me:

```
ControlObject.Name = ControlName;
```

NullReferenceException was unhandle
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Do you understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: Wrong assembly.  Your custom PictureBox1 class is *not* located in the system.Windows.Forms.dll framework assembly.

Answer (score 4):

`Assembly.CreateInstance` is expecting a type name and you appear to be passing it the name of an instance of a type (namely, a `PictureBox` named `PictureBox1`.). Therefore, `ControlObject` is `null` and thus `ControlObject.Name` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but that is why you are encountering the problem that you are. If you're trying to create a new instance of `PictureBox` I don't see why you don't just say `new PictureBox()`; this class has a public parameterless constructor. Alternatively, if you insist on reflection, you could say

```
controlType = PictureBox1.GetType();
controlObject = Activator.CreateInstance<Control>(controlType);
```

We could help more if we knew what you were trying to do instead of just throwing code that doesn't work at us and expecting us to solve world hunger.

Additionally,

```
ControlType = "System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsApplication1." + "PictureBox1";
```

1. Please rename this variable to `controlType`. You should use [camel case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx) for variable names.
2. Why do you have your application class `WindowsFormsApplication1` living in the system namespace `System.Windows.Forms`? Don't do this.

Comment: Thanks to all. All ok. But i thought that in that way (CreateInstance) i can achive transparent background in my png images. With PictureBox1 nothing works. Anyone can help? My code for transparent redraw paint e.Graphics.DrawImage(paint, x, y);

Comment: What is type of controlType variable? Please

Comment: @user432121: Ask a separate question.

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance<Control>(controlType); has no overloaded methods with 1 parameter.

Comment: I see in MSDN that it has with 1 parameter. But typyzed method not support.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. Use `(Control)Activator.CreateInstance(controlType)`.

Comment: Yeah thanks but it doesnot appear to show transparent color :(((((((((((((((((

Answer (score 1):

You're probably trying to write

```
ControlObject = new PictureBox();
```

Comment: The broplem is i have my own class PictureBox1 with overrided member Paint

Comment: @user: Then you need to write `ControlObject = new PictureBox1();`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like CreateInstance returns null, which means the type wasn't found in the assembly. Is PictureBox1 a type or an object?

Answer (score 0):

Surly your application is not in **System.Windows.Forms** namespace

```
"System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsApplication1." + "PictureBox1"
```

Try:

```
ControlObject = (System.Windows.Forms.Control)asm.CreateInstance(typeof(PictureBox));
```

or just

```
ControlObject = new PictureBox();
```

to create a new instance of control.

Or maybe you want to find an existing PictureBox control on your form?

Answer (score 0):

It means that `asm.CreateInstance(ControlType);` is returning null.

So, `ControlType` has a wrong value. It is supposed to recieve as parameter a type http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dex1ss7c.aspx and it seems that you are sending an instance `PictureBox1`.

It should be `ControlType = "System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox";`